# sum of elements in martix of matrices using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix of matrices with some arbitrary shape `(N1,N2,k,k)`, meaning `N1*N2` matrices with shape `k*k`.
I wish to calculate the sum of each matrix (of shape `(k,k)`) and convert the matrix itself with that sum.
the resulting array would be of shape `(N1,N2)`, where each element positioned in some index `i,j` is the sum of the corresponding matrix in that given index.
is there a way of doing so with **numpy operations**? (that is - no looping over `range(N1)` and `range(N2)`)

here's a simple example (Im using `*` with the first array and the second array transpose just to create the example):

```
m = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0]]).reshape(2, 2) # matrix element of size k*k (k=2)
a = np.array([m, m + 1, m + 2, m + 3])
b = np.array([m, m + 1, m + 2, m + 3])
reshaped1 = a[:, np.newaxis]  # (N1,1,k,k) where N1=4
reshaped2 = b[np.newaxis, :]  # (1,N2,k,k) where N2=4
mult = reshaped1 * reshaped2  #  (N1,N2,k,k)=(4,4,2,2)
```

I wish to create a new array `res` that will contain the sum of all `mult` elements. that can somewhat  be done with the following pseudo:

```
for i in range(N1):
    for j in range(N2):
        res[i,j] = sum(mult[i,j])
```

appreciate your help!

Comment: Take time to read the docs of `np.sum`.  Many `numpy` functions and methods have an `axis` or `axes` parameter.  It's your friend in cases like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `np.sum` with multiple axes:

```
np.sum(mult, axis=(2, 3))
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12],
       [ 0,  8, 16, 24],
       [ 0, 12, 24, 36]])
```

Comment: No problem. These are the axes/dimensions you are trying to sum according to. To understand, create a small 2d array (rectangle and not a square) and run `np.sum(a, axis=0)` against `np.sum(a, axis=1)` and look at the output. It's difficult to grasp on a 4 dim array.

Answer (score 1):

try using `np.sum(np.sum(mult,axis=3),axis=2)`

```
import numpy as np
N1=4
N2=4
m = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0]]).reshape(2, 2) # matrix element of size k*k (k=2)
a = np.array([m, m + 1, m + 2, m + 3])
b = np.array([m, m + 1, m + 2, m + 3])
reshaped1 = a[:, np.newaxis]  # (N1,1,k,k) where N1=4
reshaped2 = b[np.newaxis, :]  # (1,N2,k,k) where N2=4
mult = reshaped1 * reshaped2  #  (N1,N2,k,k)=(4,4,2,2)
np.sum(mult,axis=3)

res=np.zeros((4,4))
for i in range(N1):
    for j in range(N2):
        res[i,j] = np.sum(mult[i,j])
print(np.array_equal(np.sum(np.sum(mult,axis=3),axis=2),res))
>>> True
```

Comment: this might just work! what are the axes for ?

Comment: you can sum NumPy arrays along a certain axis, so in this case, you sum up the "mult"  array along axis=3 (the fourth axis since we are starting to count axis from zeros) and afterward summing along axis=2